# Android OkHttp InputStream java.IOException.closed

Tags: java, android, inputstream, okhttp

I use a `OkHttpClient` to download a database on the server and to copy it on my Android application, the request is ok and I get the good content.

However when I try to write my `byteStream` to my file I get a `java.IOException.closed`. Do you know what I am doing wrong ?

```
Response httpResponse = webApiClient.execute(
    new WebApiRequest(WebApiMethod.DB_DOWNLOAD), context);

if (httpResponse.code() == 200)
{
    try 
    {
        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.body().byteStream();
        File databasePath = context.getDatabasePath(Constant.DATABASE_NAME);
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(databasePath);
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Utils.DisplayException(exc, context);
    }
}
```

I also tried to read my `ByteStream` with a `BufferedSink` but the result was the same

```
BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(databasePath));
sink.writeAll(httpResponse.body().source());
sink.close();
```

StackTrace :

```
java.io.IOException: closed
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:367)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
    at com.org.dbconn.LoginActivity$DbDownloadTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:475)
    at com.org.dbconn.LoginActivity$DbDownloadTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:436)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Could you post your full stack trace please?

Comment: Are you using any interceptors that could be closing the stream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find why the stream was closed, for some test, I was checking the content of my output String with a `System.out.println`, but when you read or print the output it close automatically the stream, this is why I get an error.

In conclusion,
One thing to remember with stream : Reading or printing the outputStream will close it.

Comment: You just saved my day mahn :D. Thank you.